# How to show degrees celcius symbol in interface builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have tried Wingdings font but it just comes out plain text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

shift + option + 8

for degree sign.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly the Mac keyboard combination is alt-shift-8.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you are asking something about an ASCII code. Then Alt+K = ˚